# How to embed Gmail send email pop up to my own web app?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'd like to open a pop up to send email in my own app, just like Gmail's, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Its possible. You need to create an application on Google Developer Console and then use Gmail API. Follow, below two links to get the details:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Hope this helps.